# Moving to Swift 3.0, building issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, migration

On the process of migrating an iOS app to Swift 3.0. I have finally got rid of (all) the syntax errors.

I still seem to have quite a big issue left though.

Following is the final error message I get in Xcode, when building the project:

It is too long to include here entirely, so I decided to choose some parts with ..... (dots) on the way to shorten it.
I hope it will be enough to give an idea of what is happening.

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/UsPr_ViewController.swift
    cd /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/ViewController.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/CrossHairView.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/ATWI.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/LibBin/Swift_ToolBox/ToolBox.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/AppDelegate.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/HBModel.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/Configuration+CoreDataProperties.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/Configuration.swift ............ /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc ...........................
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UsPr_ViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UsPr_ViewController.o -embed-bitcode-marker

0  swift                    0x000000010fa5ca3d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010fa5c466 SignalHandler(int) + 470
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff968dc52a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff52e60690 _sigtramp + 3159900544
4  swift                    0x000000010d597dd2 swift::constraints::ConstraintGraph::removeConstraint(swift::constraints::Constraint*) + 690
5  swift                    0x000000010d59827c swift::constraints::ConstraintGraphScope::~ConstraintGraphScope() + 284
6  swift                    0x000000010d6315f4 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::solveSimplified(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding) + 24868
7  swift                    0x000000010d628239 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::solveRec(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding) + 681
8  swift                    0x000000010d631402 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::solveSimplified(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding) + 24370
9  swift                    0x000000010d628239 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::solveRec(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding) + 681
10 swift                    0x000000010d627b82 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::solve(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding) + 66
11 swift                    0x000000010d636f24 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::solve(swift::Expr*&, swift::Type, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding) + 5108
12 swift                    0x000000010d676f62 swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 482
13 swift                    0x000000010d679576 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::TypeLoc, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem*) + 630
14 swift                    0x000000010d6fbd38 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 488
15 swift                    0x000000010d6fbf85 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 1077
16 swift                    0x000000010d6fbc96 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 326
17 swift                    0x000000010d6fbf85 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 1077
18 swift                    0x000000010d6fbc96 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 326
19 swift                    0x000000010d6fad5d swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckFunctionBodyUntil(swift::FuncDecl*, swift::SourceLoc) + 365
20 swift                    0x000000010d6ff3fc swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckAbstractFunctionBody(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*) + 188
21 swift                    0x000000010d6b2aba swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 6714
22 swift                    0x000000010d36231b swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 5675
23 swift                    0x000000010ce05a4d performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 2765
24 swift                    0x000000010ce02f70 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17856
25 swift                    0x000000010cdbf93e main + 8302
26 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff958645ad start + 1
27 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000052 start + 1786362534
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/ViewController.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/CrossHairView.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/ATWI.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/LibBin/Swift_ToolBox/ToolBox.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/AppDelegate.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/HBModel.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/Configuration+CoreDataProperties.swift /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/Configuration.swift ........................ -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk -I /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc ............................. /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UsPr_ViewController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UsPr_ViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-hyrzzzmmftlgdcrspqcwapcblrbt/Build/Intermediates/TheApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UsPr_ViewController.o -embed-bitcode-marker 
1.  While type-checking 'setZXComputation' at /Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/UsPr_ViewController.swift:184:5
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/me/Documents/iOS/TheApp/TheApp/UsPr_ViewController.swift:233:17 - line:233:66] RangeText="choiceArray = (archiveArray as! Array)[0] as [Int]"
```

I do not expect to have clear solution here(thought it would be great).
But it would be nice if someone could point to which direction I should look at in order to build my project.
Thanks for any relevant tip.

Comment: Have you read the error and tried its suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you mean about: scrollViewDidEndDecelerating ?
I am trying now, but replacing scrollViewDidEndDecelerating by scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is not very clear.

Comment: OK. Thanks. That got me some errors out of the way already.

Comment: ... why wouldn't you try that first before posting o.0?

Comment: Right, I was not careful enough. And since I had already spend quite some time fixing syntax errors inside Xcode, I did not expect other syntax errors showing up at this level. Actually I still don't really know why those errors that I fixed, following you tip, did not show up before inside Xcode.

Comment: @Alexander I updated the post, with a different content for the error. This time I was more careful and spent quite some time fixing what I could, before posting.

Answer (score 1):

some syntax is changed in swift 3, 
e.g:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {}
```

is now

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {}
```

Comment: Yes, I just fixed those errors. I am still left with problems though. I updated the post to refelect that.